# Java switch not seeing value of expression

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have a method I created to count the number of days in the year based on the month

```
public int howManyDays()
{
    int totalDays = 0;

    System.out.println(dDay);

    switch(dDay)
    {
    case 1:
        totalDays = 0;
    case 2:
        totalDays = 31;
    case 3:
        totalDays = totalDays + 28;
    case 4:
        totalDays = totalDays + 31;
    case 5:
        totalDays = totalDays + 30;
    case 6: 
        totalDays = totalDays + 31;
    case 7:
        totalDays = totalDays + 30;
    case 8:
        totalDays = totalDays + 31;
    case 9:
        totalDays = totalDays + 31;
    case 10:
        totalDays = totalDays + 30;
    case 11:
        totalDays = totalDays + 31;
    case 12:
        totalDays = totalDays + 30;
    }

    totalDays = totalDays + dDay;

    return totalDays;

}
```

For some reason when I call it with the driver, it just returns whatever the number of dDay was, the switch isn't being entered. I know that dDay has whatever value I give it because the print statement at the start of the method confirms it. Also, if I give dDay a value of whatever IN the method before the switch, it WILL enter the switch and works as intended. I don't understand why the println can see the value of dDay but the switch can't.

Here's the method I use to give value to the data members.

```
public void setDate(int month, int day, int year)
    {
        int monthLength = 0;
        int leapYear = 0;

        dYear = year;

        if (month > 0 && month < 13)
            dMonth = month;

        if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12)
            monthLength = 31;
        else if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)
            monthLength = 30;
        else if (month == 2)
            monthLength = 28;

        if(year % 400 == 0 || year % 100 != 0 && year % 4 == 0)
            leapYear = 1;

        if (monthLength == 31 && day < 32 && day > 0)
            dDay = day;
        else if (monthLength == 30 && day < 31 && day > 0)
            dDay = day;
        else if (monthLength == 28 && day < (29 + leapYear) && day > 0)
            dDay = day;                 
    }
```

And here's my driver

```
import java.util.*;

    public class Driver
    {
        static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        public static void main (String[] args)
        {
            Date zeroDate = new Date ();

            zeroDate.setDate(6,11,2016);
            System.out.println(zeroDate);
            System.out.println(zeroDate.howManyDays());

        }
    }
```

And constructors

```
public class Date
{
    private int dMonth;
    private int dDay;
    private int dYear;

    public Date()
    {
        dMonth = 1;
        dDay = 1;
        dYear = 1900;
    }

    public Date (int month, int day, int year)
    {
        dMonth = month;
        dDay = day;
        dYear = year;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the whole class?

Comment: I don't believe you. Prove me otherwise.

Comment: I believe  you.  I am interested in the declaration of `dDay`.  Is it `int`?  Or something different like `char`?  The wrong declaration could give the behaviour you describe.

Comment: why `switch(dDay)` with 12 cases, it's the day, right?, not the month.

Comment: That was it, I should've been using the month and not the day, I feel stupid, thanks mate.

Comment: I still think the logic is off.  You want to know the number of days remaining in the year, right?  So you should be subtracting the current day at the end, not adding it.  Also, you don't seem to be including December in your count.

Comment: Nor do you seem to account for leap year.